# How do I declare the constructor for a generic class with a generic base class with parameters?

Tags: c#

I want to do something like this:

```
abstract class Exception : ApplicationException
{
    protected Exception(string _message) : base(_message)
    {            
    }

    public Exception()
        : base()
    {
    }
}



class TException<P> : P
    where P : Exception
{
    static string messageStd;

    public TException()
        : base(messageStd)
    {
    }
}
```

Where I suppose any class under TException should be a children be Exception and TException

Just like this:

```
C is TException<B>, where
B is TException<A>, where
A is TException<Exception>
```

So we have:

```
C is C:B
B is B:A
A is A:Exception
```

but C# told me the base() in the constructor is of type object, not what I supposed to be P:Exception

Is anyone know if it's possible to make this?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're trying to accomplish. Can your problem/usage this be solved by simply wrapping exceptions and exposing them as an `InnerException` property? Maybe you can expand on the expected usage you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Please show more of the relevant code. `class TException<P> : P where P : Exception` is not valid, and the error you describe does not fit what you show either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fundamentally impossible.

The problem is that you are not allowed to derive a generic class from a type parameter, which you are trying to do with

```
class TException<P> : P
```

If you actually try to compile your code, you'll see this error:

```
Cannot derive from 'P' because it is a type parameter
```

The other error you are seeing (about the Object() base) is an artifact.

Note that the reason you can't derive a generic class from a type parameter is that this must be guaranteed to work at compile time, but there is no language support for constraining the type so that it is a non-sealed class.

Comment: Thank you for the explication.